# upgraded node to latest version and Node install not working

Tags: node.js

New to js, would really appreciate some help in setting up my properly working environment.
When I was using old version of node, I could easily clone git up repository and could do  `node install git-repo`. 
I cloned following repo *https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/* and receiving the following error message after switching to latest node 14:

```
pooja@encryption-task$ node install sjcl
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/encryption-task/install'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1020:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:890:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
pooja$ node --version 
v14.2.0
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Which node version were you using before?

Comment: `npm install sjcl`   ???

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to do `npm install sjcl`? `node install` is not a command, and it is producing that error because it is trying to run a script called 'install'. By the way, you don't need to clone the Git repo in order to install a package from the `npm` registry

Comment: Ohh God, :/ :/ right, npm and not node.  umm, than? could I simply do `npm install sjcl`?

Comment: @Pooja yes exactly, just `npm install sjcl` will work, as it will install the package from the npm registry

Comment: thanks, appreciate it. @jones, thanks, so relieved to hear it :D :)        
   Now, getting on the right path of learning JS ;)   thanks guys..

Comment: @Pooja no problem